# Fermats factorization method not functioning

Tags: java, factorization

I'm working on a program to compare different algorithms for factorization of large integers. One of the algorithms I'm including in the comparison is Fermats factorization method. The algorithm seems to work just fine for small numbers, but when I get larger numbers I get weird results.

Here's my code:

```
public void fermat(long n)
{
    ArrayList<Long> factors = new ArrayList<Long>();
    a = (long)Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n));
    b = a*a - n;
    b_root = (long)(Math.sqrt(b)+0.5);
    while(b_root*b_root != b)
    {
        a++;
        b = a*a - n;
        b_root = (long)(Math.sqrt(b)+0.5);
    }
    factors.add(a-b_root);
    factors.add(a+b_root);
}
```

Now, when I try to factor *42139523531366663* I get the resulting factors *6194235479* and *2984853201*, which is incorrect since **6194235479 * 2984853201 = 18488883597240918279**. I figured that I got this result because somewhere in the algorithm I got to a point where the numbers became too big for a long or something similar, so the algorithm got a bit messed up because of that. I added a check which calculated the product of the two factors and compared with the input value, so that I'd get an alert if the factorization was faulty:

```
long x,y;
x = factors.get(0);
y = factors.get(1);
if(x*y!=n)
    System.out.println("Faulty factorization.");
```

Interestingly enough, the check passed as true and I didn't get the alert. I tried just printing the result of the multiplication and this actually resulted in the input value. So my question is why does my program behave like this, and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is an overflow in a `long` somewhere, because longs have 64 bits and

```
42139523531366663 + 2^64 = 18488883597240918279
```

For sufficiently large numbers, you may need switch to using [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: So the factors I got are correct modulo 2^64? I see. Using BigInteger instead might prove difficult though, since I haven't found any simple way to calculate the square root of a BigInteger. I'll have to look for a solution to this. Thank you!

Comment: You can use bisection: the square root of a positive integer x > 1 must be between 1 and x, so compute the midpoint, square it, and recur on the remaining half where the square root resides, stopping when the two endpoints become equal. Or use Newton's method of derivatives, or even Heron's method, which dates to the ancient Babylonians about three thousand years ago; either works perfectly well using integers. Ask a separate question if you can't figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because there's an error in multiplying large numbers too?

That may be a valid enough reason. This is what makes the program think that it's factorization is right, but when you actually multiply the numbers without using the program, you discover the error.